# "Microsoft SQL Server" in SQL server trace file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have a question on SQL server traces.

In my trace, I see a lot of "Batch Completed" traces that appear with application name as "Microsoft SQL Server". I understand what is happening in other traces where applications are SQLAgent (a SQL agent job step executing), .Net SQLClient Data Provider (a .Net app running a SQL), SQLCMD e.t.c. but I am not sure what creates the trace with "Microsoft SQL Server".

What generates these traces? Is there a way to identify how the batch is executed by "Microsoft SQL Server"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change you settings for the profile to exclude things you don't want. Look for the SQL statement and batch stuff.

Comment: Yes, that I am clear about. I just want to know what shows up as application "Microsoft SQL Server"? Is the server running SQL? If yes then how?

Comment: I don't have profiler at home (SQL express).  Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: I see deprecation announcement events and all I am trying to find out is whats running these SQLs. Hostname for these traces is my SQL server and application name is Microsoft SQL Server. What could possibly be executing these? Is it a DTS, SSIS package on the server? Or is it some sort of batch process? When the trace says SQLCMD or SQLAgent as application I know what it means. Event example - SET ROWCOUNT will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it.

Comment: What about username?  That may narrow it down.